# Kotlin/Java functional and immutable way of collecting a map in a map

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream, kotlin, immutability

Currently i'm reading a file through the Java API and adding items to a map through the method foreach which forces me to make use of the mutablemap. Is there a way of collecting the items without the mutablemap? I know there is a method collect but I couldn't get it working.

the current way:

```
    val result = mutableMapOf<Int, MutableMap<Int, Double>>()
    Files.lines(Paths.get(folderPath))
                    .map { line -> line.split(",") }
                    .map { items -> Triple(items[0].toInt(), items[1].toInt(), items[2].toDouble()) }
                    .forEach { (id, article, rating) ->
                        if (result.containsKey(id))
                            result[id]!!.put(article, rating)
                        else
                            result.put(id, mutableMapOf(Pair(article, rating)))
                    }
```

EDIT:

my goal is to merge the triple objects based on the first value of the triple.
So a scenario would be two triple objects(1, 2, 5.5) and (1,3, 5.5). The first value of the triple is the user id, the second is the article id and the third is the rating of the article. 
after merging there would be one single entry in the map containing the first key = the user id, the first value of the triple, and the value would be a map containing the articles which the user rated.

It is currently working how I want it to work, but I was curious if there was a more functional way of solving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
val result: Map<Int, Map<Int, Double>> = Files.lines(Paths.get(folderPath))
        .map { it.split(",") }
        .collect(groupingBy({ it[0].toInt() },
                toMap<List<String>, Int, Double>({ it[1].toInt() }) { it[2].toDouble() }))
```

The compiler didn't seem to be able to infer the types for `toMap`, so I added a type hint there.

I will point out that Kotlin doesn't have an immutable `Map` implementation. The default returned by `mapOf` is `java.util.LinkedhashMap` which *is* mutable. It's just that the `Map` interface doesn't expose the mutating methods (like `put`, `putAll`). And you can freely assign a `MutableMap<Int, MutableMap<Int, Double>>` to a `Map<Int, Map<Int, Double>>`, which is also what I'm doing here with the type annotation on `result`, I'm forcing the static type to be the immutable `Map`.

Comment: Thanks! So the type hint is the List<String>?

Comment: @ErikW The type hint is `<List<String>, Int, Double>`, besically filling in every generic type of the method.

Comment: So the list<String> is a placeholder just to fill the generic types of the method?

Comment: @ErikW No, at runtime there is no `List<String>`. Normally you would just call `toMap(...)` without the `<List<String>, Int, Double>` but in this case, the compiler can not figure out what the generic types of the method should be. So I'm explicitly telling it which types to use.

Answer (score 3):

I am not comfortable enough with `Kotlin`, but it seems that you should be using a simple : `Collectors.collectingAndThen`. Something like:

```
  System.out.println(Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 1)
             .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                  Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()),
                       Collections::unmodifiableMap)));
```

The idea is that you collect to a mutable map and then wrap that into an ImmutableMap.

If by the way you have `guava` on the class path - it has build collectors that collect to an `ImmutableMap`.